# how to make the rails commands shorter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to make rails commands shorter. That is to say, I want to type

```
r g scaf User name:string age:integer
```

instead of

```
rails g scaffold User name:string age:integer
```

Do you know how to customize the shortcuts? I'd appreciate your advice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why `r g scaf`? Lets make it even shorter.

You can use `bash aliases` to create alias for a long command. ie. make commands shorter.

1. Open up the terminal and `cd` into your home directory.
2. Then `ls -a` to look for a file called `.bashrc`. If that doesn't exist create one using

   `touch .bashrc`
3. Then add `alias rgs='rails g scaffold'` at the end of the file.
4. Open up a new terminal for the changes to take effect or
   without logging out, you can also use `source .bashrc` to reload the `bash aliases`
5. Now you should be able to do

   `rgs User name:string age:integer`

Note: Before executing this command, make sure that you're in a directory which holds a `rails` project. Otherwise `rails` will suggest you to create a new project first.

Comment: +1 for the alias creation. I also save all my aliases in a separate file and source that file in .bashrc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I've solve the issue owing to you.
I use OS X, and I changed .bash_profile instead of .bashrc.

Comment: @Arun Kumar Could you please accept my question as a good question? I cannot ask a question anymore.